# First Eigenvector is non-vanishing?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, spectral-theory

Let $M$ be a closed (compact without boundary) submanifold in $\mathbb R^N.$ Then for a second-order symmetric (say with respect to $L^2$) elliptic operator $L$ acting on $C^\infty(M),$ we have the spectral theory, saying that the eigenvalues are discrete and increasing (or decreasing, depending on the sign convention). Also, we can take the first eigenfunction being positive.

My question is as follows. Suppose now the operator is acting on vectors, for example, smooth normal vector fields. (Thus, $L\colon \Gamma(NM)\to \Gamma(NM)$ where $\Gamma(NM)$ is the space of smooth sections of $NM.$) I guess that we could still have the spectral theory, in the sense that the eigenvalues are discrete and increasing. However, I am not sure if we could have a similar statement for the positivity of the first eigenvector. A possible statement I could say is like that the first eigenvector is non-vanishing. (i.e., I guess if $L$ is a second-order symmetric elliptic operator acting on $\Gamma(NM)$ and
$$LV=\mu_1V$$
where $\mu_1$ is the first eigenvalue, then either $|V|\equiv 0$ or $|V|$ is non-vanishing.

However, I am not sure this could be derived using the same argument in the scalar case, since it seems to require some maximum principle argument.

Has anyone heard of this kind of statement for differential operator acting on bundle-valued sections?

Comment: For your question are you still assuming $L$ is linear?

Comment: To act on vector fields, shouldn't it be $L:\Gamma(TM)\to\Gamma(TM)$? Usually, $C^\infty(TM)$ represents the space of smooth maps $TM\to\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @JackT Yes! Linear, symmetric and elliptic.

Comment: @Kajelad Oh you are right. That's what I'd like to say. Thanks for reminding me!

Comment: @User: There is no such result for general elliptic operators. Say $L = \Delta$ (the positive-definite Laplacian) and let $\lambda > 0$ be an eigenvalue of $L$. Then $L - \lambda I$ is a perfectly good second order symmetric elliptic operator (we added only a low order term) but $L - \lambda I$ has eigenvalue $0$. The result about the positivity and the fact that $0$ is not an eigenvalue is special to the Laplacian (or other specific operators) and indeed is related to the maximum principle. In general, you can only say that the eigenvalues are discrete and bounded from below.

Comment: @levap Thanks for your comment! However, I am not going to say the eigenvalues is positive or anything like this. What I'm interested in is the non-vanishing of the first eigenfunction.

Comment: @User: Sorry, I completely missed the fact that the question is about the eigenfunction. Still, the answer to your question is no:  Let $M = S^2$. Then any vector field $V$ on $M$ must have a zero irregardless of whether it is an eigenfunction of some elliptic operator or not. So the topology of the manifold plays a role.

Comment: @levap Thanks for your explanation! It makes sense. How about the general case if TM is replaced with any other vector bundles? (In fact, the operator I care about is acting on the normal bundle of M...)